# Where are the default colors for charts in Chart.js defined when using it with ChartKick?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I'm using Chart.js with ChartKick:

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js

I cannot find where the default colors are defined in their code for each new line/dataset that you add. E.g. see this chart below:

[image: Example Chart]

There are 8 lines, and I haven't set any of their colors explicitly; they are set by default automatically. Although I want to be able to refer to those colours for another more complex chart I'm defining so that my colors can be consistent across all my charts.

I've searched through the github repo and the docs (e.g. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html) but cannot find a thing. Does anyone know where they are defined?

Comment: Fyi for a hard-coded solution, here are the first 20 colors Chart.js uses: `['#3366CC', '#DC3912', '#FF9900', '#109618', '#990099', '#3B3EAC', '#0099C6', '#D47', '#6A0', '#B82E2E', '#316395', '#949', '#2A9', '#AA1', '#63C', '#E67300', '#8B0707', '#329262', '#5574A6', '#651067']` (derived by creating a chart with 20 lines and using the Chrome DevTools "Eye Dropper" to determine the colors). This isn't ideal though since it won't keep updated with Chart.js updates and is limited to a fixed amount of colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are defined by Chartkick rather than Chart.js. [Source](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/blob/945c9ed70c70d7fda572fb7073e55259fb19ad0c/src/adapters/chartjs.js#L59-L63)

```
let defaultColors = [
  "#3366CC", "#DC3912", "#FF9900", "#109618", "#990099", "#3B3EAC", "#0099C6",
  "#DD4477", "#66AA00", "#B82E2E", "#316395", "#994499", "#22AA99", "#AAAA11",
  "#6633CC", "#E67300", "#8B0707", "#329262", "#5574A6", "#651067"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Chartkick, but here's a general JS solution for Chartjs:

```
const x = [1,2,3,4,5]
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: x,
        datasets: range(20).map(i => ({
            data: x,
        }))
    },
})

const rgbToHex = (r, g, b) => '#' + [r, g, b].map(x => {
    const hex = (x*1).toString(16)
    return hex.length === 1 ? '0' + hex : hex
}).join('')

let chartColors = chart.config._config.data.datasets.map(d => rgbToHex(...d.borderColor.slice(4,-1).split(", ")))
chartColors = Array.from(new Set(chartColors))

console.log(chartColors)

// ['#36a2eb', '#ff6384', '#ff9f40', '#ffcd56', '#4bc0c0', '#9966ff', '#c9cbcf']
```